# How to call a UserControl's methods from a Windows.Form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

The form has a button and a panel with a UserControl which has a ListBox and a TextBox.

When I click the Windows.Form button it calls UserControl's Add()

```
listBoxTitles.Items.Add(metroTextBoxTitles.Text);
metroTextBoxTitles.Clear();
```

Which simply adds whatever the UserControl's TextBox.Text has to the UserControl's ListBox.

For some reason nothing happens when i click the button.
Why. Nothing on the UserControl can be changed or used? Or does it change but doesn't update/show what's going on?

Comment: Debug the code.  Put a stop on the click method and go though it line by line to see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what was happening was, when you create a UserControl and add it to the Window.Form the Form's designer already initiates that UserControl:

```
private UserControl userControl1;
```

So in order to solve the issue i just needed to use the UserControl which the designer code created:

```
usercontrol1.add();
```

And everything is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with communication between containers is to implement an observer class

The observer pattern is a software design pattern in which an object, called the subject, maintains a list of its dependents, called observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes, usually by calling one of their methods. 
(wikipedia)

the way i do this is creating an Observer class:

```
1    public delegate void dlFuncToBeImplemented(int signal);
2    public static event dlFuncToBeImplemented OnFuncToBeImplemented;
3    public static void FuncToBeImplemented(int signal)
4    {
5         OnFuncToBeImplemented(signal);
6    }
```

so basically: first line says that there would be a function that somebody else will implement

second line is creating an event that occur when the delegated function will call

and the third line is the creation of the function that calls the event

so in your UserControl you should add a function like this:

```
private void ObserverRegister()//will contain all observer function registration
{
    Observer.OnFuncToBeImplemented += Observer_OnFuncToBeImplemented;
    /*and more observer function registration............*/
}


void Observer_OnFuncToBeImplemented(int signal)//the function that will occur when  FuncToBeImplemented(signal) will call 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Signal received!", "Atention!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
}
```

and in your Form you should do something like:

```
public static int signal = 0;

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Observer.FuncToBeImplemented(signal);//will call the event in the user control
}
```

and now, you can register this function to a whole bunch of other controls and containers and they will all get the signal

I hope this would help :)